# Swift ReactiveCocoa issue when using rac_textSignal()

Tags: swift, reactive-cocoa

Hi guys I am trying to test the example of "Observing text edits" from https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa

However when i try to use `rac_textSignal()` signal I got an error saying "Value of type UITextField has no member "rac_textSignal"

Can someone please point out what I am doing wrong here?
Thank you so much.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var textField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let searchStrings = textField.rac_textSignal()
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you added the framework correctly ('Getting started' part of the readme)? This error suggests that the compiler doesn't know of the extension.

Comment: Do other methods of ReactiveCocoa work?

Comment: I used cocoapods to add reactivecocoa to my project. Reactivecocoa is imported into the project. When i press command click it does link to the method. Somehow I am unable to post any screen shot in the questions form, the image upload button is gone...

Answer (score 1):

import ReactiveCocoa wherever you are using it.

```
import ReactiveCocoa
```